# Why is Last Windows Update date not set in Registry when Updating via COMObject?

Tags: powershell, windows-update, windows-registry, com

When i manually Update a Windows Machine (W2K3) via the yellow icon in the Taskbar, i can get the last Install date via the Registry:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\Results\Install").LastSuccessTime
```

But when invoking the Update via a PS Script Using:

```
New-Object -ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.Session'
```

The Registry Entry is not Updated.
Why is this the case? Do i have to script this myself? Is this a option to be set in 'Microsoft.Update.Session'? 
Is there another way asking a machine when Last Updates were installed?

Comment: does running "wmic qfe" at an elevated command prompt give you what you need?

Comment: Could be a Workaround but i really wonder why i got different behaivour doing a Task manual or with COM Automation.